# How to validate a Host field in python pydantic?

Tags: python, hostname, pydantic

when you have host field to validate and host can be:

ipv4 address: 127.0.0.1

ipv6 address: 2001:db8:ff00:42

example.com

int.domain: puny£code.com

11.11.101.11.example.org

Any suggestion, how to validate the field using pydantic?

Comment: I don't know pydantic, but any of these value types can be described by some sort of parsing and validation, so the whole "host field" is an aggregate of those types. If any of them parse successfully, then the field entry is valid.

Comment: You would have better chances of getting help if you show some research effort.

Answer (score 3):

I'd look up some regexes and use `constr(regex=...)` or use some premade types from https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/ and  https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#urls

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#arguments-to-constr

then use

```
from typing import Union
from ipaddress import IPv4Address
from pydantic import BaseModel, HttpUrl, parse_obj_as


class X(BaseModel):
    host: Union[HttpUrl,IPv4Address,...]

parsed_host = parse_obj_as(X, your_host)
```

Comment: can you describe more about what the regex should have in it?.. just "use a regex" and a link to the docs for constr isn't particularly helpful! .. pydantic actually provides IP validation and some URL validation, which could be used in some `Union`, perhaps additionally with a regex

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: @ti7 updated a bit, does that fit?

Comment: @Leemosh But it won't solve when you have a host like 11.11.101.11.example.org

Comment: Then use the regex inside constr as I suggested earlier. After few secs of googling I found `reg = "^(?=.{1,255}$)[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z](?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]|-){0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)*\.?$"
` 
`constr(regex=reg)` which works with that weirdy host.